# Check Syntax of file if edited via Github Web GUI

Tags: github

Tech writers are going to edit text in JSON files via github in our project. Since they never used a IDE (and don't need to) we think about using the web GUI of github. We have a CI, but it would be very cool, if we could run a check before the commit gets done.

Example:

Step 1: tech writer opens in github the JSON file
Step 2: tech writer updates a string
Step 3: tech writer presses button to save the changes
Step 4: Some simple script executes and checks the content of this particular file.
Step 5a: Everything fine? Then commit - END
Step 5b: There is a syntax error. Show the error message to the tech writer.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

GitHub doesn't provide this functionality, and it's not likely anyone else does, either.

In order to do this, GitHub would have to have a non-bare repository on their servers and let you run an arbitrary script.  Bare repositories are packed and can be much smaller than a full working tree, and even if GitHub had a working tree, it wouldn't necessarily be on your branch, which would delay the process.  Running an arbitrary script is a security risk, and it's not guaranteed that your script would run fast enough for the process to complete in a reasonable amount of time.  Your script would also need to run via the API, which has hard limits on response times.

There is GitHub Actions, which lets you do this, but that doesn't provide real-time checking like you want.  It is appropriately sandboxed and single use so you can arbitrary scripts.

I should note that Git also doesn't provide real-time checking here: the best it can do is `pre-commit` hooks to prevent you from committing bad changes (if you've chosen to enable them).